# Redirect to index if authenticated

Tags: php, laravel-5

i'm new in laravel.
i want to set redirect to `example.com` if logged success.
i have change in `RedirectIfAuthenticated` class

from

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->check())
    {
        return new RedirectResponse(url('/home'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

to

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->check())
    {
        return new RedirectResponse(url('/'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

it still redirect to `example.com/home`

is there someone who can help?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do redirection from your controller:
I believe you only want to redirect user once and not whenever auth middleware is called.

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $credentials = [
        'email'    => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    ];

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials, Input::has('remember'))) return redirect(url('/home'));

}
```

Comment: thank you @Digitlimit.
i have seen video tutorial from jeffery, it just add property `protected $redirectTo = '/'` on AuthController class.

Comment: Ok. great. That's just another easier way of doing it in Laravel 5.